# Incrementing table column for order entry

Tags: php, mysql, methods

I have a table that stores orders. 
id (auto increment)  an oid (not auto incremented) and then the order details.
some orders can have multiple entries, this is why i have an ID and an Oid(order id)
so if you order 3 xwidgets and 4Zwidgets they go under the same OID

I am using the following code to assign the next OID number and am wondering if this is the best way:

```
$maxquery = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(oid) FROM ordr") or die(mysql_error());
$maxresult = mysql_fetch_array($maxquery);
$maxid = $maxresult['MAX(oid)'];
$oid = $maxid + 1; -- this gives me a new OID for the next entry since i can not auto increment this column
```

Comment: First, you could simplify that SQL to `SELECT MAX(oid) + 1 AS next_oid FROM ordr`.  Second, the generation of the new OID is risky unless you lock or otherwise transactionally protect its generation and subsequent use.  Third, don't do it this way at all -- see Brendan's answer instead.

Comment: Thanks for that... You are right Brendan's answer is what I needed.

Comment: did i get down voted because that was a stupid question?

Comment: @DanielHunter - I'm guessing people voted the question because it's "obvious", but of course, it's only obvious if you already know the answer :p I wouldn't take it personally, and keep in mind that it only takes one up-vote to counteract 5 down votes.

Comment: ;-) After seeing it, it is obvious. I keep trying to minimize the number of tables and it really just makes it harder that way. thanks again.

Comment: @DanielHunter, even after the edits for spelling and code formatting I find the question a bit hard to read.  However, it's certainly a fair question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [auto-increment columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). This will let you insert the data, and MySQL will pick an index for you. You'll need to denormalize your data to do this though.

You'll want two tables: `orders` and `order_items`, where:

```
orders
------
order_id
[any other columns]


order_items
-----------
item_id
order_id
[any other columns]
```

Insert the order into the `orders` table with a `NULL` `order_id` and record the `order_id` that MySQL sets. Now insert the `order_item` using the `order_id` you have, and let it auto-generate the `item_id`.

This way, MySQL will generate the numbers, so you don't need to worry about two orders trying to use the same order ID. Also, any order information won't be duplicated for each item in the order.

Comment: I knew i was missing something very simple. This makes perfect sense. Guess I just needed another head to push me in the right direction. Thank You!!